# Problema con tablas en bootstrap 4 en linux

Tags: bootstrap, linux, bootstrap-4

Hace un tiempo que vengo trabajando en Windows y tengo una pc vieja con linux mint para algunas cosas. 
Hace unos días en mi computadora que uso a menudo instale linux mint 18.3 pero cuando estaba maquetando una pagina con bootstrap 4 me encuentro con que ciertas cosas no me funcionan. Como las clases: .table-hover, .table-striped, etc.
Mirando la web desde la otra pc (que tiene linux mint como mencione), desde mi celular con android o en windows funciona todo bien.

Ya actualice el kernel del sistema, tengo los drivers de nvidia actualizados. Probé con varios navegadores. Active y desactive la aceleración de hardware (me pidieron que pruebe con eso pero no resulto). Y nose que otra cosa mas hice pero no puedo resolverlo.

Lo curioso es que con las tablas con "estilo negro" (clase: .table-dark) si me funciona todas las tablas bien.

Si alguien tiene alguna pista que decirme estaría muy agradecido.

Saludos!

Agrego una de las tablas que tengo como ejemplo:

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped no-margin" id="cua-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">DNI</th>
        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
        <th scope="col">Apellido</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <? if (!empty($lista["cuartelero"])) : ?>
        <? foreach($lista["cuartelero"] as $key => $row) :?>
          <tr>
            <td scope="row"><?=$key; ?></td>
            <td><?=$row["dni"]; ?></td>
            <td><?=$row["nombre"]; ?></td>
            <td><?=$row["apellido"]; ?></td>
          </tr>
        <? endforeach; ?>
      <? endif; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sin el código en tu pregunta, ¿Cómo podemos ayudarte?

Comment: Actualiza la pregunta con tu codigo. Yo uso linux y nunca he tenido ese problema y no tiene nada que ver.

Comment: Buenas tardes fredyfx. Ahi agregue una de las tablas que tengo. Pero de igual manera, si entro a la documentacion de bootstrap 4 tampoco me carga las clases en las tablas que no sean "negras". y como dije, esto que estoy maquetando solo en mi propia pc no lo veo bien. si lo miro desde cualquier otro equipo (sea con linux, windows o android) lo veo bien. Saludos!

Comment: ¿Que navegador estas usando en linux? ¿Que distribución? Hasta hace poco me encontré con que iceweasel no andaba muy bien. Ubuntu se regresó a FireFox. Algunas distribuciones traen navegadores que no se han actualizado hace bastante.

Comment: Buen dia Angel, estoy usando Linux Mint 18.3. El navegador que viene por defecto es Firefox, Me recomendaron instalar Chrome para probar pero no fue la solucion. Tambien instale el opera (simplemente por seguir probando) pero me sucede lo mismo. Lo de iceweasel me entere, ya que la ultima vez que use linux venian casi todos con el mismo y ahora casi todos con firefox.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás cargando las librerías en tu página? ¿y cómo estás corriendo tu página en local? ¿puedes poner un ejemplo de la URL que ejecutas?

Comment: Cargo los CSS y JS como siempre. Por ejemplo: <link href="<?= base_url('assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">. Si no me cargaria el CSS o el JS tendria problemas mayores. Lo que me sucede es algo puntual. La web que tengo si la cargo desde otra pc se ve bien. A igual que si lo hosteo en otro lado. Aca tengo problema solo en mi maquina con bootstrap en una pc particular y solo con linux. Ya que desde windows 10 no tengo problemas. En cuanto a la url por ejemplo: http://localhost/_intranet/.